How to get the number of scheduled messages for an ActiveMQ Classic destination?
I schedule messages with the AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY header as documented for ActiveMQ Classic. This works as intended, but now I would like to retrieve the number of scheduled messages for a specific queue.
To achieve this, I looked at the DestinationViewMBean:
private DestinationViewMBean getDestinationViewMBean(String destinationType, String destinationName) throws MalformedObjectNameException {
         
     ObjectName activeMQ = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=" + broker.getBrokerName() + ",destinationType=" + destinationType + ",destinationName=" + destinationName);
     DestinationViewMBean destinationViewMbean = (DestinationViewMBean) broker.getManagementContext().newProxyInstance(activeMQ, DestinationViewMBean.class, true);
    
     return destinationViewMbean;

}

System.out.println("------> InFlight=" + getDestinationViewMBean(endpointType,endpointName).getInFlightCount());
System.out.println("------> Enqueue=" + getDestinationViewMBean(endpointType,endpointName).getEnqueueCount());
System.out.println("------> Dequeue=" + getDestinationViewMBean(endpointType,endpointName).getDequeueCount());
System.out.println("------> Forward=" + getDestinationViewMBean(endpointType,endpointName).getForwardCount());
System.out.println("------> StoreMessageSize=" + getDestinationViewMBean(endpointType,endpointName).getStoreMessageSize());
System.out.println("------> QueueSize=" + getDestinationViewMBean(endpointType,endpointName).getQueueSize());
System.out.println("------> BrowseSize=" + getDestinationViewMBean(endpointType,endpointName).browse().length);

But these methods don't give information about the scheduled messages.
Then I tried to use the BrokerViewMBean:
ObjectName[] queues = brokerViewMBean.getQueues();

for(ObjectName queue: queues){

   ObjectName object = new ObjectName(queue.getCanonicalName());

   Long scheduledCount = (Long) mbeanServerConnection.getAttribute(object, "ScheduledMessageCount");

   System.out.println("------> Scheduled Count=" + scheduledCount);

} 

This gives the error message:
javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: No such attribute: ScheduledMessageCount

I also looked at the JobSchedulerViewMBean, because this contains the method getDelayedMessageCount. This however is a global count, and not specified by destination.
How can I retrieve the number of scheduled messages for a specific ActiveMQ Classic destination?

FWIW, you could switch to ActiveMQ Artemis and use getScheduledCount.

I have a common API for both Classic and Artemis, and will also implement this for Artemis based on your suggestion.

In case anyone want to implement this for ActiveMQ Artemis:
ActiveMQServer activeBroker = broker.getActiveMQServer();
QueueControl queueControl = (QueueControl) activeBroker.getManagementService().getResource(org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ResourceNames.QUEUE + endpointName);
long numberOfScheduledMessages = queueControl.getScheduledCount();

Unclear what version of the broker you are using but in later releases the Job Scheduler MBean does allow you to get all jobs with included destination names for the scheduled Job.  You could use that API to get all scheduled jobs and then filter locally by the target destination you want to count to compute the number you are after.  There is no direct call to do this as it is generally pretty inefficient to do so as it requires decoding each job from the binary value encoded into the scheduler store.

I'm currently using ActiveMQ Classic 6.1.2 (JDK21).

Then you should have access to those APIs as they appear to have been added prior to that version

Based on the suggestion by Tim Bish I used the JobSchedulerViewMBean. I followed this approach:

JobScheduler service
As documented schedulerSupport support must be enabled in the broker XML configuration.


<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" schedulerSupport="true">


Retrieve the MBean

The scheduler service should now be available. You can check this by listing the MBeans:
MBeanServerConnection connection = broker.getManagementContext().getMBeanServer();

Set<ObjectName> mbeans = connection.queryNames(null, null);

for (ObjectName mbean : mbeans) {
   System.out.println(mbean);
}

There should be a service "JobScheduler". In my case:
org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,service=JobScheduler,name=JMS
Note that in my case the name of the JobScheduler is 'JMS', but could also be 'JobScheduler' or 'JMSJobScheduler'. If the ObjectName of the bean is wrong you will get the following exception:
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,service=JobScheduler,name=JMSJobScheduler

Get the JobSchedulerViewMBean

Now you can get the JobSchedulerViewMBean:
private JobSchedulerViewMBean getJobSchedulerViewMBean() throws Exception {

    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,service=JobScheduler,name=JMS");
    JobSchedulerViewMBean jobSchedulerViewMBean  = (JobSchedulerViewMBean) broker.getManagementContext().newProxyInstance(objectName, JobSchedulerViewMBean.class, true);

    return jobSchedulerViewMBean;

}

or alternatively:

private JobSchedulerViewMBean getJobSchedulerViewMBean() throws Exception {

    ObjectName objectName = broker.getAdminView().getJMSJobScheduler();
    JobSchedulerViewMBean jobSchedulerViewMBean  = (JobSchedulerViewMBean) broker.getManagementContext().newProxyInstance(objectName, JobSchedulerViewMBean.class, true);

    return jobSchedulerViewMBean;

}


Count the number of delayed messages

The JobSchedulerViewMBean has a build in method to count the number of delayed messages:
int delayedMessageCount = getJobSchedulerViewMBean().getDelayedMessageCount();
System.out.println("------> Delayed Messages Count=" + delayedMessageCount);

This however is global, if you want to filter by destination then you need to get all scheduled jobs (TabularData) and filter the items:
Collection<?> collection = getJobSchedulerViewMBean().getAllJobs(true).values();

long numberOfDelayedMessages = collection.stream()
        .map(o -> (CompositeData) o)
        .filter(row -> endpointName.equals(row.get("destinationName")))
        .count();

Note: you need to set the boolean to true on the getAllJobs method to include the destination names. This method is available since ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.4 and 6.1.0.
